# Unable to connect to mixed b/g/n wifi network on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, broadcom

I cannot connect to mixed b/g/n wifi Network. I am using **wl** drivers. Connection to other wifi networks is working well, but to this network I cannot connect from Ubuntu (from my android phone connection works)  Specifications of my wifi network are here: 
[image: Wifi configuration]

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. And my Wifi adpater is **BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter**
ouput of :

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

is :

```
PCI (sysfs)  


  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 08:3e:8e:a4:03:6d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:e4100000-e4103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: b8:88:e3:e2:ff:f7
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.0.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:44 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:e2804000-e2804fff memory:e2800000-e2803fff
```

Where shold be a mistake? Thank you.

Comment: It should be related to your modem, try to pick up `802.11b` mode only.

Comment: If I use 802.11b it works, but it limits my internet speed and this is not good.

Comment: Though I said it's related to your modem, it's not. Module of your wireless  must be old or incompatible with your router. Try to upgrade it.

Comment: Have you tried with a fixed channel; 1, 6 or 11 for example, rather than 'Auto?'

Comment: @chili555 yes, I tried all channels.

Comment: Please run and post: lspci -nn -d 14e4: Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 bo@bo-ThinkPad-Edge-E530:~$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proprietary driver wl is generally not the preferred driver for your 14e4:4727 device. Let's remove it:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And now we load the preferred driver:

```
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

It may take a reboot. Is there any improvement?