# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Broadcom Corporation Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini - Cant Find my Wifi Network

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I can't find my Wifi Network. I can see other networks though and can connect to my wifi from a different PC.

My Wifi information are

- Wireless Radio: Enabled
- 802.11 Mode: Mixed 802.11n, 802.11g and 802.11b
- Channel Width: 20/40MHz
- Channel: 13
- Network Name (SSID): Michigan
- Wi-Fi Protected Setup: Enabled/Configured
- Security: WPA/WPA2-PSK

I just installed Ubuntu on my Laptop and am new to Linux.

I tried [Unable to connect to mixed b/g/n wifi network on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553155/unable-to-connect-to-mixed-b-g-n-wifi-network-on-ubuntu) because it sounds like my problem but when I reboot at the end my Wifi-Card has no driver active. I can choose one but that is just the old one.

Here is a link to the result of the script

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yaq4c3oflotdjdv/wireless-info.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: Can you add what wifi card `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and what kernel `uname -r`

Comment: The output of `iwconfig` would be very useful too. In short, please run the [WiFi disgnostics](/q/425155) and [edit] your question to include a link to the results. It'll contain all the info Jeremy and I ask for and more.

Comment: Is there a way to change my WiFi-Settings to avoid this problem?

This is the router I'm using http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine figured it out. I had to change my Channel from 13 to 11 (anything below 12 should work).
It seems my laptop or at least the wifi card was made in the USA and there Channel above 11 are used/were used for something else. So their wifi cards only check up to 11.